# Sonar Configuration on Windows 2003 server

Tags: .net, hudson, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have installed `sonar`, `sonar-runner` and `hudson` on `windows 7` machine its working fine , but when I want to replicate these steps on my production server which has `windows 2003 server` I got the error of `fx-cop` file path although I have provided the `FxCop` installation path in  **project.properties** but still its looking

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft FxCop 1.36\FxCopCmd.exe**

Other than properties file in project where its stores the default path ????

How can i fix this path issue on `windows 2003 server`.Any help ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not set the property in the "sonar-project.properties" files, because this property may not point to the same folder on different machines.

Instead, you should set this property in the "conf/sonar-runner.properties" file that is located in the %SONAR_RUNNER_HOME% folder where you installed Sonar Runner. It should look like:

```
sonar.fxcop.installDirectory=C:/FooFolder/FxCopInstallFolder
```

Note that you must use '/' and not '\'.